# How to spy on methods of service when the service is provided in the root of Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit test for a angular component using karma-jasmine. I have used providers in my ProfileComponent and injected ProfileService.

**profile.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile',
    templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./profile.component.scss'],
    providers: [ProfileService]
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    public data;

    constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        await this.profileService.login();
        this.profileService.getData('A').subscribe((result) => {
            this.data = result;
        });
    }

}
```

**profile.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProfileService {

    private baseUrl: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.baseUrl = 'https://localhost:4002';
    }

    public async login() {
        const loginUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/api/Login`;
        return this.http.post(loginUrl, {}, { headers }).toPromise();
    }

    getData(id: string) {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/api/GetData/${id}`;
        return this.http.get(url, { headers });
    }
}
```

**profile.component.spec.ts**

```js
const data = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

describe('Client.App.ProfileComponent', () => {
    let component: ProfileComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture < ProfileComponent > ;
    let profileService: ProfileService;
    let profileData;

    beforeEach(async (() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterTestingModule],
            declarations: [ProfileComponent],
            providers: [ProfileService],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
        profileData = new Subject();
        profileService = TestBed.inject < ProfileService > (ProfileService);
        spyOn(profileService, 'login').and.returnValue({});
        spyOn(profileService, 'getData').and.returnValue(profileData);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('shall create the component', () => {
        profileData.next(data);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

I added a debugger and checked that its failing in login. So, I have two questions:

1. As I have used providers in the `Profile Component`, can I inject the `ProfileService` in the `profile.component.spec.ts` file as it will create two instance of the same service?
2. How to spy on login() and getData() of ProfileService as below statement is not working...?

```js
spyOn(profileService, 'login').and.returnValue({});
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **As I have used providers in the Profile Component, can I inject the Profileervice in the profile.component.spec.ts file as it will create two instance of the same service..??**

Answer: You should create a `Stub` for the service to replace dependency on actual `ProfileService` using `useClass`

```
export class ProfileServiceStub {
    getData(id: string) {
       return of({some_obj: "value"})
    }
}
```

and **in spec.ts**

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterTestingModule],
            declarations: [ProfileComponent],
            providers: [ {provide: ProfileService , useClass: ProfileServiceStub } ], // <-- useclass here
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
```

2. **How to spy on login() and getData() of ProfileService as below statement is not working...?**

Answer: Make the service `public` in component constructor as below:

```
constructor(public profileService: ProfileService) { }
```

I would strongly recommend you to read [my article on something similar where I have tested the component](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49)

Answer (score 0):

1.) I think what you have is fine, putting `ProfileService` in the `provider` array in `TestBed.configureTestingModule` is good and when the component gets created, it knows how to make it. Each time the component gets created, it will be a separate provider but this will be the case whether providing the provider in the component or globally since a test constructs and destructs (beforeEach.... TestBed.configureTestingModule....).

2.) Try `spyOn(profileService, 'login').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));

Side note: The `ngOnInit` needs an async decorator in order to use await.

Comment: How can I add async decorator on ngOnInit in spec file...?

Comment: Put `async` in front of it like: `async ngOnInit() {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to provide a mock instead of providing the actual service instance. After that you need to provide a fake implementation of that service method. Please find below the required changes and inline comments.

```
const data =['A','B','C'];

describe('Client.App.ProfileComponent', () => {
    let component: ProfileComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProfileComponent>;
    let profileService: jasmine.SpyObj<ProfileService>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
       // create a spied service and use it inside providers array
        profileService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ProfileService', ['login', 'getData']);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterTestingModule],
            declarations: [ProfileComponent],
            providers: [ { provide: ProfileService, useValue: profileService ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
       // provide fake implementation to service methods
        profileService.login.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('success'));
        profileService.getData.and.returnValue(of(data)); // of is rxjs operators- import
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('shall create the component', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Comment: its failing in login and I am not able to proceed further